# my external css file is not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I don't know why it is happening but I am only able to use only 1 style sheet at a time whether it can bootstrap style sheet or my external style sheet please help

**Homepage.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="untitled.css"> -->
    <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="untitled.css" />
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
                        <img src="skins/images (2).jfif" id="rectangle_6">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="skins/images (2).jfif" id="rectangle_6">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
                        <img src="skins/images (2).jfif" id="rectangle_6">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Untitled.css**
[image]

**when I remove my external CSS file link the output is like this**
[image]

**when I remove my bootstrap CSS file link the output is like this**
[image]

Comment: Paste your external CSS code here

Comment: rel might be case sensitive?

Comment: @AmanSharma it is too long do you still want me to paste it here

Comment: Have you tried `rel="stylesheet"`  instead of `rel="StyleSheet"`

Comment: @NnajiVictor yes i have tried that too

Comment: @NaveenSingla create a jhttps://jsfiddle.net/ simple!

Comment: @AmanSharma https://jsfiddle.net/naveensingla/qL01gnrm/2/

Comment: @NaveenSingla You added "div { position: absolute; }" on line "11" and "#rectangle_6 {}" It breaks all the UI

Comment: @NaveenSingla https://jsfiddle.net/y5b1oc9w/

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the comment.

Comment: @AmanSharma one more doubt now I have removed position: absolute property but now all other components get affected any solution to this problem

Comment: @NaveenSingla please check now https://jsfiddle.net/73cd65nq/1/

Comment: @AmanSharma can you please tell me what kind of changes have you made in css file